# Why do we say 'Tearing about'

Tags: expressions, british-english

Why do we say 'tearing about' meaning rushing around in a rather haphazard way. I can't find the expression in any dictionary or thesaurus and am not sure if  I am spelling it correctly. Most concerned it could die out if parents don't continue to use it to chastise lively children! Any ideas?

Comment: Just look up _tear_ at the freedictionary, and select the appropriate sense from those listed - it appears in both the AHDEL and Collins. Various prepositions / particles may be added: tore up the street / tore along the road / tore into the car park / tore along.

Comment: Which dictionaries are you checking? It's present on http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tear and the http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tear and my old hardcopies of the Macquarie and 5th ed Concise Oxford Dictionary of Current English?

Comment: What is the tearing hurry now? Check the right dictionaries first. :)

Answer (score 1):

The core meaning of the verb *tear* expresses forceful action. When people *tear about*, in the Oxford English Dictionary’s definition they ‘move with violence or impetuosity’. Such usage is colloquial, but it has a long history, being first recorded in the seventeenth century.